# pointer arithmetic on elements and beyond. what is wrong with this code?

Tags: c, pointers

Please, what is wrong with this code. it's supposed to print until y[4] and then break out of the while loop, but it prints until y[12] and breaks thence; I think printing between y[5] to y[12] is wrong. It was taken from a website as an example that pointer arithmetic is limited to the elements of the array and one element beyond.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   int x[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
   int y[5];
   int *ptr = x;
   while (&y[i] != (ptr+5)){
        y[i] = x[i];
        printf("Value of y[%d] is : %d\n", i, y[i]);
        i++;
   }

   return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: (checking it out, but I am almost certain there is no guarantee y will be allocated imidiately after x)

Comment: You rather want `while (&x[i] != ptr + 5)`.

Comment: I believe yours is correct, H2CO3. y[i] was declared but not initialized. I just realized it. Found it on a website. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your condition `(&y[i] != (ptr+5)` is wrong. Y is an array that is pointing to a completely different area in the memory than x. So the condition will stay true.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `&y[i] != (ptr+5)` does not make sense here. Why are you comparing `y` with `ptr`? They are pointing to different memory locations. They can never be the same since they are pointing at two different locations. You just need to check for this:

```
while (i<5)
```

See full code [here](http://ideone.com/uYjw2N).

Comment: i think the essence of the while control flow is to show that a pointer can point to one element beyond its array; so an array should be in the while.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the array `y` will be placed at a specific position in relation to the array `x`. So what you are exploiting is compiler-specific behavior, that may change depending on compiler used, compiler version or even compiler flags.